# Why do programs close before completion during for loops? Why did mine?

Tags: c

The Program stops after the for loop in the function mush is ran. The code compiles in minGW without errors. When ran the program never prints "still running". How is this possible? The purpose of mush is to delete characters in string 1 that match string 2.

```
void copy(char to[], char from[])
    {
        int i;
        i = 0;
        while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
            ++i;
    }

void mush(char s1[],char s2[]) {
    char temp[MAXLINE]; 
    int i, t; 

    copy(temp, s1);
    printf("String One: %sString Temp: %s" , s1, temp);
    printf("Temp Before: %s", temp);


    for (i = 0; (s1[i] != '\0') && (s1[i] != '\n'); i++) {
        if (s1[i] == s2[i]) {printf("s1 = s2");}

        temp[t++] = s1[i];
        printf("loop:");

    }
    printf("Still running");
    copy(s1, temp);
}
```

Comment: The debugger has the answer.

Comment: doesn't look like `t` is ever initialized.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*.

Comment: `char temp[MAXLINE];` was not nul-terminated before passing to your home-brew `copy` which relies on that.

Comment: @WeatherVane `copy()` doesn't require the destination string to be null-terminated, only the source string.

Comment: `mush` never removes anything from the string. When it sees a duplicate it prints a message, but it still copies it.

Comment: Not initializing `t = 0;` is almost certainly the problem. You're writing outside the array boundary and causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @Barmar i was talking about the `copy(s1, temp);`, not the earlier `copy(temp, s1);` and the unterminated `temp` is the source not the destination.

Comment: @WeatherVane Didn't notice that, but the program never gets there.

Comment: `temp` is terminated by the first `copy()`. The `for` loop will not write past the null terminator (if `t` is properly initialized) so it will still be null-terminated.

Comment: What's the point of calling `copy(temp, s1)` before the `for` loop? The loop also copies from `s1` to `temp`.

Comment: @Barmar I see little point to most of this code. Not sure what it is supposed to be doing. It *looks* like an attempted unit test for `copy`, a homegrown `strcpy`, but hard to say. I suspect three is more on the way. The name suggests some element stripping will be in play sometime in the future ("strip all spaces, blah blah...").

Comment: Yeah, it clearly doesn't meet **The purpose of mush is to delete characters in string 1 that match string 2.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a few points that need to be looked at

1 ) you did not initialize the variable `t` used in the for loop. It has a garbage value.

2 ) the increment of `t` does not depend on any condition, so better to move it in to the for loop's increment part

Below is a working copy of your code with some modifications for styling

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

void copy(char to[], char from[])
    {
        int i;
        i = 0;
        while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
            ++i;
    }

void mush(char s1[],char s2[]) {
    char temp[MAXLINE]; 
    int i, t; 

    copy(temp, s1);
    printf("String One: %s\nString Temp: %s\n" , s1, temp);
    printf("Temp Before: %s\n", temp);


    for (i = 0, t = 0; (s1[i] != '\0') && (s1[i] != '\n'); i++, t++) {
        if (s1[i] == s2[i]) {printf("s1 = s2 (%c %c)\n", s1[i], s2[i]);}

        temp[t] = s1[i];
        printf("loop:\n");

    }
    printf("Still running\n");
    copy(s1, temp);
}

int main(void) {
  char s1[]="this is a test";
  char s2[60];

  mush(s1,s2);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: With your fix, there isn't even any reason to have separate `i` and `t` variables, since they're always the same.

Comment: Just wanted to keep the code as similar as the OP. Lots of changes (such as using a for loop for copy()) can be done.